# A interesting question about time complexity

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory, nlp-question-answering

during my classroom i asked this question to my teacher and he couldn't answer that's why i am asking here.
i asked that during a code , what if we have a loop to run from 1 to 10 , does the complexity would be O(1) {big O of 1} . heanswered yes. so here's the question what if i have written a loop to run from 1 to 1 million .is it sill O(1)? or is it O(n) or something else?

pseudo code - 
for i in range(1,1 million):
 print("hey")

## what is the time complexity for that loop

now , if you think the answer is O(n) , how can you say it to be O(n) , because O(n) is when complexity is linear. 
and what is the silver lining? when a code gets O(1) and O(n) .
like if i would have written a loop for 10 or 100 or 1000 or 10000 or 100000. when did it transformed from O(1) to O(n).

Comment: You need to decide what `n` represents. Once you have that, you'll have your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing the term. Time complexity for a given algorithm is given by the relationship between *change in execution time* with respect to *change in input size*.

If you are running a fixed loop from 1 to 10, but doing something in each iteration, then that counts as O(10), or O(1), meaning that it will take *the same time each run*.

But, as soon as the number of iterations starts depending on the number of elements or tasks, then a loop becomes O(n), meaning that the complexity becomes *linear*.
 The more the *tasks*, proportionally more the *time*.

I hope that clears some things up. :-)

Comment: thanks a lot , i guess i do understand but still it baffles my brain that a block of code that is going to run for a million or 100 million times is going to be considered O(1) complexity .

Comment: @RohitSharma Basically O(1) means constant time. It does not imply any kind of speed.

Comment: You should not consider O(1) complexity to be related to time in any way. In fact, you may think that O(1) is the complement of O(f(n)). Anything not fitting in O(f(n)) is O(1). :-)

Comment: @RohitSharma please select an answer, if it answers your question. If not, please modify your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, O(10000000) and O(1) are equal, Let me quickly explain what complexity means.

What we try to represent with the abstraction of time (and space) complexity isn't how fast a program will run, it `what is the growth in runtime (or space) given the growth in input length`.

For instance, given a loop with a fixed number of iterations (lets say 10), it doesnt matter if your input will be 1 long or 10000000000000, because your loop will ALWAYS run the same number of iteration therefore, no growth in runtime (even if that 10 iterations may take 1 week to run, it will always be 1 week).

but, if your algorithm's steps are dependent in your input length, that means the longer your input, the longer your algorithm's steps, the question is, how much more steps?

in summary, time (and space) complexity is an abstraction, its not here to tell us how long things will take, its simply here to tell us how the growth in time will be given growth in input, `O(1) == O(10000000)`, because its not about how long it will take, its about the change in the runtime, O(1) algorithm can take 10 years, but it will always take 10 years, even for very large input length.

Comment: let me take a formal explanation to your question: is your algorithm, which is `f(1000000) is in O(1)?` for this, we need to prove that there are `c > 0` and `n > 0` such that `0 ≤ f(n) ≤ cg(n)`, since `f(n)` and `g(n)` are constant, there is `c > 0` that satisfy the equation, therefore, `f(1000000) is in O(1)`